# vim netrw close netrw buffer on file open

Tags: vim, netrw

When I open netrw and choose a file, it opens in a new buffer. This means that if I do `b%` to go to previously opened buffer I will go back to netrw, rather then the file I was editing before.

How can I change this behaviour so I can either open new file in netrw's buffer or close the buffer that I used for file opening?

Answer (score 1):

There is the option for netrw `g:netrw_altfile`

Here is the helptext

```
some like |CTRL-^| to return to the last
edited file.  Choose that by setting this
parameter to 1.
Others like |CTRL-^| to return to the
netrw browsing buffer.  Choose that by setting
this parameter to 0.
default: =0
```

If you want to close the netrw buffer after opening a file, you will need to write some vim script I think, there are some examples online but I haven't seen one I would recommend.